# Anyone ported the QP state framework for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, avr

In reviewing possible approaches for my data logging project, I have found the book "Practical UML statecharts in C/C++" to be very interesting for more serious work with the Arduino. QP is a family of ultra-light, open source, state machine-based frameworks for embedded systems and they distribute code and ports for their frameworks (GNU GPL2) at http://www.state-machine.com/ where they have a port for the AVR and AVR mega using the WinAVR/Gnu C++ tool set.

Although the chip specific headers are appropriate, has anyone created a board BSP file or had any experience with these frameworks? I am just starting with the book, so any comments greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 on Jason S's comment about giving +1 for mentioning QP state chars. Oh, also Star and +1 one the topic... cause it sounds groovy and i look forward to answers :P (sorry for the spam, just in a funny mood today ;) )

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid this kind of thing like the plague.

Most "serious" low level software I've encountered has been a state machine in this form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    STATE_INIT,     // Description
    STATE_RUNNING,  // Description
    STATE_COMPLETE  // Description
} state_t;

int main(void)
{
    state_t state = STATE_INIT; // setup the initial state

    while(1)
    {
        os_run(); // call the OS services (poll the UART, check buttons, etc.)

        switch(state)
        {
            case STATE_INIT:
                state = STATE_RUNNING;
                puts("init");
                break;
            case STATE_RUNNING:
                state = STATE_COMPLETE;
                puts("running");
                break;
            case STATE_COMPLETE:
                puts("complete");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are plenty of other good approaches in C/C++, but they're not my favourite.

The big problem with tools like QP is that it's often very hard to do things they don't want you to. If you do choose to fiddle with code manually you'll have to maintain the special case forever.

I'd say, UML statecharts are a fantastic tool for documentation, teaching and analysis. But, not for actual programming - there are much better tools for that :)

Comment: Don't forget the licensing fees for QP if your code is proprietary.

Comment: Minor improvement on the state machine code: it often helps reliability to queue state changes and only ever change the actual state right before the switch statement.  That way you don't have to worry about an interrupt changing your state to STATE_INIT right after you thought you changed it to STATE_COMPLETE.

Answer (score 3):

I personally have not used the QP framework/library, because of the GPL license.  At the time, I didn't think my employer was ready to cough up the dough for me to experiment with HSM's (hierarchical state machines) using QP.  I had to implement my own that was similar to QP when I was refactoring an awful state machine that took up hundreds of lines of code like Joby's example but times 1000. The old design which was borrowed to get features up in running on a tight deadline was a terrible pain to maintain.  I dreaded trying to add something new to it for fear of breaking something else.

I redesigned the code into an HSM that made a lot more sense to me personally on how the system should behave. It worked far better than I could imagine.  It was so much easier to modify and maintain then I could ever dream.  I even had to almost redo much of the state machine, because of unexpected behavior in system.  It was so much easier to fix with the framework I had made, and I'm sure it would have been just as easy in QP.  The framework I built became popular and spread to some other complex state machines inside our codebase.

I did have a friend implement the quantum framework using Java in a robot that worked out pretty well.  It was part of the robot's decision making algorithm based on certain inputs. It was natural fit, given the decisions it had to make based on the robot's state.

What I understand of the beauty of QP is the ability to have a ready to framework for a state machine design that is optimized for your processor and not have to rely on CASE tools spitting out inefficient boilerplate code.  But, I would only use QP if you have set of complex set of state machines to implement that describe your design.

If all you have is something as simple as Joby's example, then just do it like he explained.  But if you find your state machine growing and growing with all kinds of "if else" statements wrapped around different conditions...then it might be time to try something like QP to break it down into HSM's.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Joby's example a cleaner way to implement a very large state machine is to replace the case statement with an array of function pointers. Then you can isolate all of the code for a particular state inside a function. I've found that implementing it this way requires far less program memory.

Answer (score 1):

> replace the case statement with an
>   array of function pointers

Which is how the QP stuff works. The representation of a state is just a function pointer (to the function for the current state). In C++ it could be a pointer to member function, but basically the same. The current state function is called with events, as well as with some pseudo-events (entry, exit), one of which is always unhandled and is used to determine the state nesting when doing nested transitions (QP supports hierarchical state machines).

Miro Samek says that he's going to be doing an Arduino-targeted port soon.